# Existence of solution for linear matrix inequality?

Tags: inequality

Suppose $x$ is a $n\times1$ column vector. How to know whether the following matrix inequality has solution or not?

$$Ax\leq B$$
where $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n\times 1$ column vector.

Comment: What is your definition of $\leq$? Are we talking component-wise? Are $A$ and $B$ fixed $m\times n$ and $m\times1$ matrices respectively?

Comment: Look for a solution to the appropriate linear program.